# How to query specific category or all categories inside the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column name "category". In PHP, I use a sql prepare statement to select all records belonging to a specified category. I do this with category=? and then add the variable with a category value. This works fine.

However, how can I select all categories within this same query?

I tried using `null` and `''` as category value but this did not work. Copying the whole code part with for another query might create spagetti code, thus I was wondering if there is a better option.
Are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on what @JamesMarks was offering, it would be simpler to use a query like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = ? OR 1 = ?;"
```

Then pass your $category for the first parameter, and either 1 or 0 as the second parameter.  If you pass 1, then the second term becomes `1 = 1`.  That's always true, so the whole expression is always true.  If you pass 0, then the second term is `1 = 0` and that's always false, but then the whole expression will be true only if `category = $category` matches.

That's simpler and better style than designating a special value 0 for "any category."

An alternative solution is to build the query dynamically:

```
$where = array();
if ($category) {
    $where[] = "category = ?";
    $params[] = $category;
}

... perhaps add more terms to $where conditionally ...

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
if ($where) {
    $query .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an automatically generated ID (AUTO_INCREMENT or IDENTITY, depending on your database engine), you can use a WHERE clause similar to the following.

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = $category OR $category = 0;"

Just pass a value of 0 to your $category variable when you want "All Categories".

If you don't want to pass a value for $category, and instead want to be able to pass a blank $category, you can set $category to 0 before you build the query string:

$category = ( empty($category) ? "0" : $category );
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = $category OR $category = 0;";

...or you can rewrite on a single line, as below.

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = $category OR " . ( empty($category) ? "0" : $category ) . " = 0;"

Comment: I don't get it yet. You are using the $category two times and $category = 0 will select a specific category not all. What am I missing?

Comment: I got the idea now, but your solution is not working. The OR part is always executed. I want a specific category IF specified else ALL categories.

Comment: if you don't want to specify 0 (zero) for all categories, you can modify the query to look like this:
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = $category OR ". (!empty($category)?$category:"0")." = 0";